# Would you use MVC 2 already or MVC 1? - S#arp Architectur + Spark View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine, s#arp-architecture

I am starting to develop a complex web application using S#arp Architectur and the Spark View Engine.

By default MVC 1.0 is used.

But i am thinking about upgrading everything to ASP.NET MVC 2.

Would u start developing in MVC 1 and upgrade to version 2 later or do the upgrade straight from the beginning?

Thanks for your advice,

-Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the day it's risk vs reward as always.

MVC 2 is pretty much rock solid in my experience, but it's still beta software so if it goes tits up then whoever made the decision to use beta is in the firing line.

Do you actually **need** the features? If your gonna go and spending a lot of resources on coding the kind of features that are already included then perhaps it is better to use v2 straight away.

Answer (score 1):

**MVC 2**

Regarding microsoft products (imho):
Version 1 is a beta - buggy and incomplete. Version 2 is what vesion 1 should be.

I am using MVC 2 RC for a very big CMS project and haven't had any issues. If you don't know MVC version 1 very well, I would go MVC 2, so you don't end up having to learn the old stuff and the new and get all confused.

I can attest that 2 is stable in my experience and I think the new **[features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053072/asp-net-mvc-2-rc-best-features/2053124#2053124)** make it worth the risk. (Ask me again in a month after my project is *LIVE* :P )

---

**UPDATE:** Project is now live and running great on MVC 2. A full featured running on MVC 2 handling tens of thousands of users per day. *NOW* is the time to jump into MVC 2, it is awesome!!!

---

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how comfortable you are in using Beta software to develop production software.

If you feel that MVC 2.0 is stable enough for your production environment then go for it.  We have a policy here that we never use Beta s/ware for anything other than training or investigation.

I think developing in 1 and then upgrading would be prudent yeah.