# ASP.NET-MVC 2 RC Best Features

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been working with MVC 1 for some time now and have decided to finally give MVC 2 a shot.

My question is, for those who have been using 2 for some time what are the features or areas I should be looking at first?

I know there's a bunch of new stuff in there but would like to target my learning to specific areas rather than go looking myself for a couple of weeks.

I realise this is kinda lazy but I have tight deadlines here at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Scott Guthries blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx) to get some ideas of the new things.

Answer (score 3):

[Strongly type Html Helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx).

No more "magic strings" to pass a property name into a helper means more compile time checking, less wasted time debugging.

Comment: +1 Yeah I saw that the other day in another post and thought that was huge.

Answer (score 2):

[XVal style validation attributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/rickandy/archive/2009/10/03/client-side-validation-for-mvc-2-p2.aspx) that can automatically generate corresponding client side validators.

Answer (score 1):

[Single-project areas.](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/31/single-project-areas.aspx)

Provides a way to conceptually separate a large web application into logical "areas" while maintaining the integrity of a single web application.

Answer (score 1):

**Areas**!!!

Using areas in a new publication CMS system to keep the admin controller/views seperate from the regular front end of the site.

The strongly typed helpers is good too. (See @womp's answer)

[Scot Gu's Blog Post on MVC 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx)